# C# - Lambda vs nested loops

Tags: c#, linq, loops, lambda, nested-loops

Is is possible to convert following into a simpler more readable linq or lambda expression?

```
Dictionary<int, int> selectedProgramTierCombo = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach (int mainTierID in doc.TierID)
{
    foreach (PriceProgram priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms)
    {
        foreach (ProgramTier progTier in priceProgram.Tiers)
        {
            if (progTier.TierID == mainTierID )
            {
                selectedProgramTierCombo.Add(priceProgram.ProgramID, progTier.TierID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially doc.TierID is a an array (int[]) of TierIDs that client is currently on. Also the doc object contains a CommitmentProgram object which contains a list of PriceProgram. So, All I am trying to do is get the PriceProgram.ProgramID for each TierID.

The relationship between PriceProgram and TierID is that each PriceProgram has a list of tiers (ProgramTier object) and ProgramTier oject contains the corresponding TierID that we already have.

Let me know if my explaination doesn't make sense and I'll try to elaborate.

**Edit**

Jon, 
I am getting **The name 'priceProgram' does not exist in the current context** error when I try to compile what you have suggested:

```
Dictionary<int, int> selectedProgramTierCombo = 
    (from mainTierID in doc.TierID 
     from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms 
     **join progTier in priceProgram.Tiers on mainTierID equals progTier.TierID**
     select new { priceProgram.ProgramID, progTier.TierID }) 
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ProgramID, x => x.TierID);
```

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires '1' type arguments.

Comment: I've provided updated code based on Jon's initial answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use another `from` clause instead of the `join`... although it sounds like you don't need that bit at all, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, it's very easy - but I'll have to change the type of your `selectedProgramTierCombo` variable, as otherwise it won't compile:

EDIT: Oops, given that the tiers depends on priceProgram, you need another nested `from` clause, I think:

```
Dictionary<int, int> selectedProgramTierCombo =
    (from mainTierID in doc.TierID
     from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms
     from progTier in priceProgram.Tiers
     where mainTierID == progTier.TierID
     select new { priceProgram.ProgramID, progTier.TierID })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ProgramID, x => x.TierID);
```

At least, that's what I *think* you want. If you could clarify what you really want instead of `List<int, int>` (which isn't valid) we can help further.

To be honest, it's not clear to me why you're using `progTier` at all - you know that `progTier.TierID` is the same as `mainTierID`, and you're not using it apart from that...

Comment: Perhaps he meant (or needs) `List<Tuple<int,int>>`, assuming `x.ProgramID` was not a unique identifier for the purposes of this collection? It wouldn't change the answer greatly, however.

Comment: @Anthony: Possibly. It's hard to tell :(

Comment: I was thinking about approaching this with a join prior to your comment. Somebody mentioned SelectMany(), which I have never used, is this not a viable solution? Also, I don't usually bother with casting, just punch the whole thing into a var, especially if the structures never leaves the function block. This is purely a matter of style, but may be useful to the poster.

Comment: @Eugarps, (a) Jon's code is the query expression syntax version of `SelectMany`. If he were to rewrite this using fluent syntax, it would involve that method. (b) There's no casting here, he's just being explicit with his declaration rather than using the inference of `var`, presumably for the express purpose of demonstrating the fact that the OP has an invalid collection type and a correct one is altogether different.

Comment: Actually Jon, you got it, I meant Dictionary<int, int> not List<int, int>. Also, you are right about progTier vs mainTierID ... they are the same so I do have to use progTier. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: @Jon, OP is having trouble making this compile. It's the right idea, though, just needs to be rearranged slightly.

Comment: @Anthony: Hmm... I don't think it *should* need to be rearranged. Experimenting...

Comment: @Anthony: Doh. Okay, yes. There are two options here... will edit.

Comment: @Jon, I also added a couple of variations in an answer below that each use Join. I assume one is likely more optimal than another, but I haven't taken the time to flesh out a full scenario to test.

Comment: Is there a way we can avoid null reference exceptions (not talking about try catch but a null check perhaps)?

Comment: @Robert: I'm sure there is, but it would depend where the null reference is.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's answer is the right idea, just needs to be rearranged in order to compile. Here are two options.

```
var dict = (from mainTierID in doc.TierID
            join f in
                (from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms
                    from progTier in priceProgram.Tiers
                    select new { priceProgram.ProgramID, progTier.TierID })
                on mainTierID equals f.TierID
            select f).ToDictionary(f => f.ProgramID, f => f.TierID);


var dict2 = (from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms
                from progTier in priceProgram.Tiers
                join mainTierID in doc.TierID on progTier.TierID equals mainTierID
                select new { priceProgram.ProgramID, progTier.TierID })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.ProgramID, x => x.TierID);
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. The first variation really helped clarify what is going on within the code =)

Answer (score 1):

The Single kind of bugs me, but I have to go with what's being asked for.

```
Dictionary<int, int> selectedProgramTierCombo =
(
  from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms
  let tierId =
  (
    from progTier in priceProgram.Tiers
    where doc.TierID.Any(mainTierID => mainTierID == progTier.TierID)
    select progTier.TierID
  ).Single()
  select new
  {
    ProgramID = priceProgram.ProgramID,
    TierID = tierID
  }
).ToDictionary(x => x.ProgramID, x => x.TierID);
```

This is what I'd be more comfortable with:

```
ILookup<int, int> selectedProgramTierCombo =
(
  from priceProgram in doc.CommitmentProgram.PricingPrograms
  from progTier in priceProgram.Tiers
  where doc.TierID.Any(mainTierID => mainTierID == progTier.TierID)
  select new
  {
    ProgramID = priceProgram.ProgramID,
    TierID = progTier.TierID
  }
).ToLookup(x => x.ProgramID, x => x.TierID);
```

Comment: Thank you David. Is there a specific reason why you are using ILookup instead of Dictionary? If so, i'd like to know why.

Comment: Since there might be more than one item in doc.TierID, and there might be more than one matching tier in priceProgram.Tiers... a given pricing program might have multiple main tiers (at least in a technical sense).  ILookup allows me to have multiple values for a key.